# Vim or Emacs-like modeline magic support for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, modeline

I'm writing a script using Qt's [ECMAScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ecmascript.html). The files use the extension `.qs`, which VSCode does not currently have syntax highlighting for. `javascript` syntax highlighting, however, is plenty pretty to satisfy me.

Is there any way to map `.qs` to `javascript` from **within** the `.qs` file? This would be similar to [File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) for Emacs or [Modeline Magic](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) for Vim.

I know that I can map `.qs` to `javascript` in the VSCode settings as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_can-i-map-additional-file-extensions-to-a-language), but would prefer something that ships with the file.

There's also [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrislajoie.vscode-modelines) that seems to achieve this, but I'm curious if there are other options.

#### Example modelines for both Vim and Emacs:

```
# vim: set ft=js
// -*- mode: js; -*-
```

Preferably this would be built into VSCode, but it doesn't look like that is going to happen based on the answer to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1651#issuecomment-346306841).

Looking for other hacks or alternatives that people know of!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now I can't find any support for modelines natively in VS Code.

You can, however, get similar functionality from a an extension like this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrislajoie.vscode-modelines